# Running a pipelin in linux

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line

I have this script

```
#!/bin/bash
module load bedtools/2.21.0
bamfiles=(
/temp/hgig/fi1d18/1672_WTSI-COLO_023_1pre/mapped_sample/HUMAN_1000Genomes_hs37d5_RNA_seq_WTSI-COLO_023_1pre.dupmarked.bam
/temp/hgig/fi1d18/1672_WTSI-OESO_005_w3/mapped_sample/HUMAN_1000Genomes_hs37d5_RNA_seq_WTSI-OESO_005_w3.dupmarked.bam
/temp/hgig/fi1d18/1672_WTSI-OESO_036_2post/mapped_sample/HUMAN_1000Genomes_hs37d5_RNA_seq_WTSI-OESO_036_2post.dupmarked.bam
/temp/hgig/fi1d18/1672_WTSI-COLO_021_1pre/mapped_sample/HUMAN_1000Genomes_hs37d5_RNA_seq_WTSI-COLO_021_1pre.dupmarked.bam 
/temp/hgig/fi1d18/1672_WTSI-COLO_027_1pre/mapped_sample/HUMAN_1000Genomes_hs37d5_RNA_seq_WTSI-COLO_027_1pre.dupmarked.bam 
/temp/hgig/fi1d18/1672_WTSI-COLO_011_1pre/mapped_sample/HUMAN_1000Genomes_hs37d5_RNA_seq_WTSI-COLO_011_1pre.dupmarked.bam 
/temp/hgig/fi1d18/1672_WTSI-COLO_176_1pre/mapped_sample/HUMAN_1000Genomes_hs37d5_RNA_seq_WTSI-COLO_176_1pre.dupmarked.bam 
/temp/hgig/fi1d18/1672_WTSI-COLO_170_1pre/mapped_sample/HUMAN_1000Genomes_hs37d5_RNA_seq_WTSI-COLO_170_1pre.dupmarked.bam 
/temp/hgig/fi1d18/1672_WTSI-COLO_141_1pre/mapped_sample/HUMAN_1000Genomes_hs37d5_RNA_seq_WTSI-COLO_141_1pre.dupmarked.bam 
/temp/hgig/fi1d18/1672_WTSI-COLIVM_005_1pre/mapped_sample/HUMAN_1000Genomes_hs37d5_RNA_seq_WTSI-COLIVM_005_1pre.dupmarked.bam 
/temp/hgig/fi1d18/1672_WTSI-COLO_099_1pre/mapped_sample/HUMAN_1000Genomes_hs37d5_RNA_seq_WTSI-COLO_099_1pre.dupmarked.bam 
/temp/hgig/fi1d18/1672_WTSI-COLO_085_1pre/mapped_sample/HUMAN_1000Genomes_hs37d5_RNA_seq_WTSI-COLO_085_1pre.dupmarked.bam 
/temp/hgig/fi1d18/1672_WTSI-COLO_075_1pre/mapped_sample/HUMAN_1000Genomes_hs37d5_RNA_seq_WTSI-COLO_075_1pre.dupmarked.bam 
/temp/hgig/fi1d18/1672_WTSI-COLO_027_a_RNA/mapped_sample/HUMAN_1000Genomes_hs37d5_RNA_seq_WTSI-COLO_027_a_RNA.dupmarked.bam 
/temp/hgig/fi1d18/1672_WTSI-COLO_021_a_RNA/mapped_sample/HUMAN_1000Genomes_hs37d5_RNA_seq_WTSI-COLO_021_a_RNA.dupmarked.bam 
/temp/hgig/fi1d18/1672_WTSI-OESO_036_a_RNA/mapped_sample/HUMAN_1000Genomes_hs37d5_RNA_seq_WTSI-OESO_036_a_RNA.dupmarked.bam 
/temp/hgig/fi1d18/1672_WTSI-COLO_005_1pre/mapped_sample/HUMAN_1000Genomes_hs37d5_RNA_seq_WTSI-COLO_005_1pre.dupmarked.bam 
/temp/hgig/fi1d18/1672_WTSI-COLO_023_a_RNA/mapped_sample/HUMAN_1000Genomes_hs37d5_RNA_seq_WTSI-COLO_023_a_RNA.dupmarked.bam 
/temp/hgig/fi1d18/1672_WTSI-OESO_121_1pre/mapped_sample/HUMAN_1000Genomes_hs37d5_RNA_seq_WTSI-OESO_121_1pre.dupmarked.bam 
/temp/hgig/fi1d18/1672_WTSI-OESO_013_a_RNA/mapped_sample/HUMAN_1000Genomes_hs37d5_RNA_seq_WTSI-OESO_013_a_RNA.dupmarked.bam 
/temp/hgig/fi1d18/1672_WTSI-OESO_005_a_RNA/mapped_sample/HUMAN_1000Genomes_hs37d5_RNA_seq_WTSI-OESO_005_a_RNA.dupmarked.bam 
/temp/hgig/fi1d18/1672_WTSI-COLO_011_a_RNA/mapped_sample/HUMAN_1000Genomes_hs37d5_RNA_seq_WTSI-COLO_011_a_RNA.dupmarked.bam 
/temp/hgig/fi1d18/1672_WTSI-COLO_019_1pre/mapped_sample/HUMAN_1000Genomes_hs37d5_RNA_seq_WTSI-COLO_019_1pre.dupmarked.bam
)

for file in "${bamfiles[@]}"; do
    fname=$(basename "$file")
    fdir=$(dirname "$file")
    bamtofastq -i "$file" -fq "${fdir}/${fname%.bam}.fq"
done
```

I run this

```
[fi1d18@cyan01 ~]$ chmod +x run.sh

[fi1d18@cyan01 ~]$ run.sh
basename: invalid option -- 's'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
./run.sh: line 30: bamtofastq: command not found
basename: invalid option -- 's'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
./run.sh: line 30: bamtofastq: command not found
basename: invalid option -- 's'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
./run.sh: line 30: bamtofastq: command not found
basename: invalid option -- 's'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
./run.sh: line 30: bamtofastq: command not found
basename: invalid option -- 's'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
./run.sh: line 30: bamtofastq: command not found
basename: invalid option -- 's'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
./run.sh: line 30: bamtofastq: command not found
basename: invalid option -- 's'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
./run.sh: line 30: bamtofastq: command not found
basename: invalid option -- 's'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
./run.sh: line 30: bamtofastq: command not found
basename: invalid option -- 's'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
./run.sh: line 30: bamtofastq: command not found
basename: invalid option -- 's'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
./run.sh: line 30: bamtofastq: command not found
basename: invalid option -- 's'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
./run.sh: line 30: bamtofastq: command not found
basename: invalid option -- 's'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
./run.sh: line 30: bamtofastq: command not found
basename: invalid option -- 's'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
./run.sh: line 30: bamtofastq: command not found
basename: invalid option -- 's'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
./run.sh: line 30: bamtofastq: command not found
basename: invalid option -- 's'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
./run.sh: line 30: bamtofastq: command not found
basename: invalid option -- 's'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
./run.sh: line 30: bamtofastq: command not found
basename: invalid option -- 's'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
./run.sh: line 30: bamtofastq: command not found
basename: invalid option -- 's'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
./run.sh: line 30: bamtofastq: command not found
basename: invalid option -- 's'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
./run.sh: line 30: bamtofastq: command not found
basename: invalid option -- 's'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
./run.sh: line 30: bamtofastq: command not found
basename: invalid option -- 's'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
./run.sh: line 30: bamtofastq: command not found
basename: invalid option -- 's'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
./run.sh: line 30: bamtofastq: command not found
basename: invalid option -- 's'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
./run.sh: line 30: bamtofastq: command not found
[fi1d18@cyan01 ~]$


[fi1d18@cyan01 ~]$ run.sh
./run.sh: line 32: bamtofastq: command not found
./run.sh: line 32: bamtofastq: command not found
./run.sh: line 32: bamtofastq: command not found
./run.sh: line 32: bamtofastq: command not found
./run.sh: line 32: bamtofastq: command not found
./run.sh: line 32: bamtofastq: command not found
./run.sh: line 32: bamtofastq: command not found
./run.sh: line 32: bamtofastq: command not found
./run.sh: line 32: bamtofastq: command not found
./run.sh: line 32: bamtofastq: command not found
./run.sh: line 32: bamtofastq: command not found
./run.sh: line 32: bamtofastq: command not found
./run.sh: line 32: bamtofastq: command not found
./run.sh: line 32: bamtofastq: command not found
./run.sh: line 32: bamtofastq: command not found
./run.sh: line 32: bamtofastq: command not found
./run.sh: line 32: bamtofastq: command not found
./run.sh: line 32: bamtofastq: command not found
./run.sh: line 32: bamtofastq: command not found
./run.sh: line 32: bamtofastq: command not found
./run.sh: line 32: bamtofastq: command not found
./run.sh: line 32: bamtofastq: command not found
./run.sh: line 32: bamtofastq: command not found
[fi1d18@cyan01 ~]$
```

Comment: What is `featureCounts`?

Comment: You still haven't shown us what your `run.sh` script contains.  You've shown us the method to convert one file, what method are you attempting to convert multiple files?

Comment: Please don't express your problem using bioinformatics terminology. Most of us don't know what a bam file is, or what format a fastq file should take. Rephrase your question in computing terms (I have a file that looks like _this_ and I want to make it look like _that_. Here's what I've tried, but it does _something else entirely_.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the limited information in your question, and assuming your `bamtofastq` command is [this one](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/bamtofastq.html) from the bedtools package, I have come up with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

bamfiles=(
    /path/to/file1.bam
    /path/to/file2.bam
    /path/to/file3.bam
)

for file in "${bamfiles[@]}"; do
    fname=$(basename "$file")
    fdir=$(dirname "$file")
    bedtools bamtofastq -i "$file" -fq "${fdir}/${fname%.bam}.fq"
done
```

---

This assumes you want to manually hand jam all your bam files into the script and want the .fq files to reside in the same directory as it's corresponding bam file.  If this is not the case please provide more information that could help us answer your question more efficiently.

Comment: @FereshTeh: I've updated my code to handle your version of basename

Comment: @FereshTeh: So it looks like you don't have a bamtofastq command in your path or installed.  How do you normally run it?

Comment: @FereshTeh `module load bedtools/2.21.0` doesn't mean anything. There is no `module` command in the shell. And, assuming you mean the command from `bedtools`, you want `bedtools bamtofastq -i "$file" -fq "${fdir}/${fname%.bam}.fq"`, not just `bamtofastq`.

Comment: Just change the `bamtofastq` to `bedfiles bamtofastq` and remove the `module` line which is not doing anything. By the way, I see you have an account on [bioinformatics.se], next time, ask this sort of thing there. While this is on topic here, it is also on topic there but the people there understand the problem better and will be able to help more easily. Feel free to ping me in the site's [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58858/bioinformatics) if you still need help.

Comment: @terdon `module load package/version` is a common way to set up ones `PATH` etc. to access specific software on some systems. I don't remember what this mechanism is called, but we use it on our bioinformatics cluster at work as well, and not just for bioinfo software. Fereshteh obviously needs to access bedtools and this command allows her to do that.

Comment: @Kusalananda Oh. I stand corrected, I've never come across such a system.

Comment: Thank you to be such a helpful for helpless people